# How to fetch images synchronously

Tags: swiftui

I cannot figure out how to fetch my images in sync. At the moment, the code fetches my reel thumbnail along with my username image. However, the reel thumbnail gets fetched very fast, but the username image takes several seconds. I am not sure why or how can I access all the elements at the same time. I am using retry to fetch it, but I am under the impression the code is making multiple requests, where I'd prefer to make only one requests and get it all at the same time.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var webViewStore = WebViewStore()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            contentSection
            Divider()
            urlInputSection
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color(red: 0.15, green: 0.15, blue: 0.15))
    }

    private var contentSection: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                if let uiImage = webViewStore.fetchedUIImage {
                    Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                }

                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    userProfileSection
                    descriptionSection
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.leading, 10)
            }

            Spacer()
        }
    }

    private var userProfileSection: some View {
        HStack {
            if let userProfileImage = webViewStore.fetchedProfileUIImage {
                Image(uiImage: userProfileImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }

            if let username = webViewStore.fetchedUsername {
                Text(username)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }

    private var descriptionSection: some View {
        Group {
            if let description = webViewStore.fetchedDescription {
                Text(description)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .lineLimit(4)
                    .padding(.top, 5)
            }
        }
    }

    private var urlInputSection: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                webViewStore.loadURL(url: URL(string: "https://www.instagram.com/p/CxGEZGWrH-N/")!)
            }) {
                Text("Load")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                    .padding(.vertical, 8)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
            }
            .frame(height: 36)
        }
    }
}

class WebViewStore: NSObject, ObservableObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    @Published var fetchedUIImage: UIImage?
    @Published var fetchedDescription: String?
    @Published var fetchedProfileUIImage: UIImage?
    @Published var fetchedUsername: String?
    private var webView: WKWebView

    override init() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        super.init()
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
    }

    func loadURL(url: URL) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        fetchContent()
        attemptFetchingDescription(retryCount: 3)
    }
    
    private func fetchContent() {
        let fetchImageScript = """
        (function() {
            var imageElement = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]');
            var result = {
                imageURL: null,
            };
            if (imageElement) {
                result.imageURL = imageElement.getAttribute('content');
            }
            return result;
        })();
        """

        webView.evaluateJavaScript(fetchImageScript) { (fetchResult, fetchError) in
            if let result = fetchResult as? [String: String], let imageURLString = result["imageURL"], let validURL = URL(string: imageURLString) {
                self.loadImage(from: validURL, assignTo: \.fetchedUIImage)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func loadImage(from url: URL, assignTo property: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<WebViewStore, UIImage?>) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let imageData = data, let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self[keyPath: property] = uiImage
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    private func attemptFetchingDescription(retryCount: Int) {
        if retryCount <= 0 { return }

        let checkScript = "document.body.innerHTML.includes('Instagram')"

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(checkScript) { (result, error) in
                if let isPresent = result as? Bool, isPresent {
                    self.fetchImageURL(retryCount: retryCount)
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                        self.attemptFetchingDescription(retryCount: retryCount - 1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func fetchImageURL(retryCount: Int) {
        let fetchImageScript = "var img = document.querySelector('header img.xpdipgo.x972fbf'); img ? img.getAttribute('src') : 'Not found';"
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(fetchImageScript) { (fetchResult, fetchError) in
                if let link = fetchResult as? String, !link.contains("Not found"), let validURL = URL(string: link) {
                    self.loadImage(from: validURL, assignTo: \.fetchedProfileUIImage)
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                        self.attemptFetchingDescription(retryCount: retryCount - 1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can’t, the View shouldn’t be doing work, show a progress view while your image is loading once you have the actual UIImage you can display it. You can “preload” the code before the view shows too so it is all available at the same time.

Comment: thats what I was thinking to place a loading animation, but I looked at several apps like "repost+" and when I place the link in it, the load takes less than a second to fully render. So that left me with guessing what did i do wrong @loremipsum

Comment: Image size, cache, different ways of getting the image.

Comment: Also change ObservedObject to StateObject when initializing the model